# Shadow of a non rounded block in beamer

Tags: beamer, shadows, block

My question is simple: Is it possible to add shadow to a NON rounded block in beamer?

I've been trying it with:

```
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded=false][shadow=true]
```

But no success. I'm using the marburg theme. Here is the preamble code:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 

\author{Lorem ipsum}
\title{LOrem ipsum}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 \usetheme[hideallsubsections,left,width=2cm]{Marburg}

\usecolortheme{rose}
 \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=structure,fg=white}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{../Fotos/Logo.png}}

  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
      \begin{minipage}{2cm}
          \centering      
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \insertlogo

      \vspace{\baselineskip}
      \color{white}{\insertshorttitle[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks]}

\insertshortauthor[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks] \vspace{\baselineskip}

\insertverticalnavigation{2cm}

\vspace{10\baselineskip}

\insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{minipage}
  }

\begin{document}
...
```

Thanks in advance,

Charlie

Comment: Are you using any outer or inner additional themes? Can you show at least the relevant parts of your preamble?

Comment: No, just the color theme called rose. I posted the preamble of the code.

Comment: This can be really hard, since the shadow is only defined for rounded boxes and the definitions for the case rounded and not rounded boxes are different. I have a possible work-around (in my mind, I've not written any code yet), but do you plan to apply shadows to *all* possible boxes (theorem -like blocks, `exampleblock`, `alertblock`, etc.)?

Comment: So far, I only have regular blocks, exampleblocks and alertblocks. I don't think I will be inserting other types of blocks.

Comment: I'm thinking of maybe attach a tikz transparent block with a certain offset behind a regular block, but I don't know if this is actually possible.

Comment: There's an easier solution; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not easy natively in `beamer` (but there's an easy way to achieve it using external tools) since shadows are applied only to rounded boxes (which are built using `beamerboxesrounded`) but not to non-rounded boxes (which are built separately using `beamercolorbox`).

As an alternative, I offer you here a possibility using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to define blocks emulating those defined by the `beamer` class, but adding the shadow. In the following example I show how to easily do this defining a proper style and building shadowed clones for `exampleblock` and `alertblock`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\linespread{1.05} 

\usetheme[hideallsubsections,left,width=2cm]{Marburg}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=structure,fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
\begin{minipage}{2cm}
  \centering      
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
  \insertlogo%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
  \color{white}{\insertshorttitle[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks]}%
  \insertshortauthor[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks] \vspace{\baselineskip}
  \insertverticalnavigation{2cm}
  \vspace{10\baselineskip}
  \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber
  \end{minipage}%
}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{beamer@color/.style={top color=\kvtcb@colback,bottom color=\kvtcb@colback}}
\makeatother

\tcbset{
tcbeamer/.style={
  beamer,
  width=\textwidth+3pt,
  enlarge left by=-3pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  toptitle=0pt,
  bottomtitle=-1pt,
  }
}

\newenvironment<>{tcexampleblock}[1]
  {\begin{actionenv}#2\begin{tcolorbox}[
    adjusted title=#1,
    tcbeamer,
    colback=block body example.bg,
    colframe=block title example.bg,
    fonttitle=\large\color{block title example.fg}
    ]
  }
  {\end{tcolorbox}\end{actionenv}}

\newenvironment<>{tcalertblock}[1]
  {\begin{actionenv}#2\begin{tcolorbox}[
    adjusted title=#1,
    tcbeamer,
    colback=block body alerted.bg,
    colframe=block title alerted.bg,
    fonttitle=\large\color{block title alerted.fg},
    adjusted title=#1,
    ]
  }
  {\end{tcolorbox}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{exampleblock}<1->{Test exampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{tcexampleblock}<2->{Test tcexampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{tcolorbox} package.
\end{tcexampleblock}

\begin{alertblock}<3->{Test alertblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{alertblock}

\begin{tcalertblock}<4-6>{Test tcalertblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{tcolorbox} package.
\end{tcalertblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result, showing the new overlay-aware environments in action:

[image]

Notice that the serif class option is obsolete, so instead of

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
```

you should use

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

Comment: Hi Gonzalo! When I try to insert the tcalertblock or tcexampleblock latex says: ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `block body alerted.bg'.

What could be producing this?

Comment: @Charlie Hi. No idea. In my system there's no errors; I even asked in chat for an independent compilation (you can see the transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15442805#15442805)) and other user compiled successfully the code. If you replace that color by a "usual one", such as `red` does the problem disappear?

Comment: I think it was layer 8 error :P. It compiles but I can see that the new blocks, apparently, don't admit overlays. I'm going to accept your answer because despite the lack of tools and the complexity, you were able to make a work around successfully.
Do you think it's possible to make them admit overlays?

Comment: @Charlie Ah, I can make them overlay aware, if you want to.

Comment: That'd be great!

Comment: @Charlie Done. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks it works like a charm!

Everytime I come here to get some help I get impressed of the level of knowledge of the users here! It's really outstanding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox ). This theme has an option to switch on shadows independent of round/sharp corners: `\useinnertheme[shadow]{tcolorbox}`

Full example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 

\author{Lorem ipsum}
\title{LOrem ipsum}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 \usetheme[hideallsubsections,left,width=2cm]{Marburg}

\usecolortheme{rose}
 \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=structure,fg=white}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}}

  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
      \begin{minipage}{2cm}
          \centering      
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \insertlogo

      \vspace{\baselineskip}
      \color{white}{\insertshorttitle[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks]}

\insertshortauthor[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks] \vspace{\baselineskip}

\insertverticalnavigation{2cm}

\vspace{10\baselineskip}

\insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{minipage}
  }
  
\useinnertheme[shadow]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{title}
content...
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]